# Why WspBuilder.exe consider net framework 4.5 project as unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, packaging

I'm upgrading my VS solution from .net 3.5 to .net 4.5. I shifted to VS 2013 and change the TargetFramework. Everything is working well till this step but wspbuilder start creating problem for me and show me the below error:

```
.dll is unmanaged and is not allowed in GAC, this assembly will not be included in the WSP package!
```

What should i do with that? Is Wspbuilder doesn't support 4.5v dlls? if yes, then what could be the alternative tool for packaging?

Comment: First, .NET 4+ uses a different runtime from 3.5 so WSPBuilder can't read 4+ assemblies. Second - [you don't need it any more](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58966/how-can-i-build-a-wsp-file-for-sharepoint-2013). A Visual Studio SharePoint solution will generate a wsp when you build it. That's why WSPBuilder was never upgraded to 2010 or 2013.

Comment: yes i could understand but the problem is that Visual Studio can only create packages for sharepoint solutions only. And we have a custom solution which is then packaged with the help of wspbuilder. And i'm not sure how to convert custom solution to sharepoint solution so that i could see the built-in options, which visual studio provided.

Comment: You will have to convert your solution anyway, as I suspect your solution targets SharePoint 2007. WSPBuilder was used a lot for 2007 but wasn't really updated for 2010, 2013, as packaging improved immensely. CKS Dev Tools adds an "Import WSPBuilder Solution" menu command that could help you.

Comment: yes it was originally created for Sharepoint 2007 then upgrade by the time. There are lot of customized script written to create wsp package on built events. So i wonder if VS built-in wspbuilder feature could help me according to my needs.